# how to change recording window during xbox bar screen recording

Tags: windows, xbox, screen-recording

I need to record different windows in a same recording using screen-recording funtion in xbox bar.
However, if I switch to another window, the screen recording continue to record the previous one. If I close the previous one, the xbox also closes